# repmat in python3 for a 100 by 3 matrix without dimension error. Matlab repmat worked fine but not pytthon3

Tags: python

I have a "100 by 3" matrix called "z". Want to get this matrix repeated for 15 times and do this `(x1-w1)**2 + (H-z1)**2)` in python3.
See example below. In MATLAB it worked fine with z1=repmat(z,n,1) where n=15. Now how to fix this "z1 repmat" in python3 so that there is no dimension error for `(x1-w1)**2 + (H-z1)**2)` ?

```
# some 100 by 3 matrix
z = np.random.rand(100, 3)

H = 10
x=np.transpose(np.linspace(0,100,15)).reshape(15,1)
w=np.linspace(0,100,100).reshape(100,1)
x1=np.matlib.repmat(x,1,100).T
w1= np.matlib.repmat(w,1,15)

z1=repmat(z,n,1) # where n=15
result = (x1-w1)**2 + (H-z1)**2
```

Comment: What is the value of `n` in your case? (in `z1=repmat(z,n,1)`)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want your `z1` to be equal to `np.matlib.repmat(z, 1, n)` instead of `(z, n, 1)`.

Meaning, to match the shape of the other operand (`(x1-w1)**2` of shape `(100,15)`), for `z1` you should be repeating *columns* of `z`, not rows. Also, here I assume that your `n` is equal to 5, since this is the value that fits the example provided.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.matlib

# some 100 by 3 matrix
z = np.random.rand(100, 3)

H = 10
x=np.transpose(np.linspace(0,100,15)).reshape(15,1)
w=np.linspace(0,100,100).reshape(100,1)
x1=np.matlib.repmat(x,1,100).T
w1= np.matlib.repmat(w,1,15)

z1=np.matlib.repmat(z,1,5)
print((x1-w1)**2 + (H-z1)**2)
```

Comment: Actually, I forgot to add that "n=15". If I try this, then I am getting this dimension error: 
"ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,15) (100,45) ".                                                                                         I want to make this 100 by 45 shaped z1 matrix 3 sets of z1 after using that z1=np.matlib.repmat(z,1,15). Is there any way to loop(in my case i=3) z1 in the result so that 1st time it only takes one set of 100 by 15 matrix and 2nd time another 100 by 15 and 3rd time another 100 by 15 from that z1 100 by 45 matrix?